# BeautifulSoup Python not capturing all the HTML in a file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

so i'm using BeautifulSoup in Python (bs4) and I'm trying to extract information from a webpage. For reference the webpage I'm looking at is an advanced search engine, the corresponding HTML I want is:

```
<p class="viewing">
     Viewing: <strong>        
     1</strong> - <strong>       
     50</strong> of <strong>    
     11,204</strong> papers
</p>
```

After using bs4 in Python I try to extract it by using:

```
num_papers = soup.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/p/strong[3]')
```

Where this is the Xpath of the value `11,204` from the HTML. I am using the `lxml` parser and most answers on Stack indicated that this is a parsing issue so I looked at `html5lib` but that didn't work either. For clarity, my output yields the `type` as `NoneType` because it couldn't find this. I actually printed the soup out for this page and saw that this corresponding HTML isn't even being recorded in the soup hence the `NoneType`. I feel like it's the parser but I don't know where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<p class="viewing">
     Viewing: <strong>        
     1</strong> - <strong>       
     50</strong> of <strong>    
     11,204</strong> papers
</p>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


target = soup.find("p", class_="viewing")

print(target.contents[-2].get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
11,204
```

Or

```py
target = soup.find("p", class_="viewing").find_all_next("strong")[2]

print(target.get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
11,204
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response. This still doesn't work and I get the output `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all_next'`. Let me try and be more specific about this